# Multivariable Calculus: Deciding on a Textbook

Tags: multivariable-calculus, book-recommendation

I’m not sure if this is the right place to ask this but I may as well. I just finished AP Calculus BC this year as a sophomore, having skipped both precalc and calc AB, and I’m taking Multivariable Calculus through John Hopkins university’s online course for high schoolers next year. I wanted to get ahead of my workload as I’m taking a few other difficult classes like Discrete Math and Physics C. I’m planning to try to self study some multivariable calculus using a textbook, but I haven’t been able to find any that target my demographic in terms of previous experience; most textbooks I saw are aimed at solely university with a deeper understanding of calculus. Does anyone know of any textbooks which I could use which would include the foundational knowledge to self study effectively, and that are aimed more towards a slightly less experienced?

Comment: OpenStax Calculus, Volume 3, or the texts from Stewart or Thomas. You also should really make sure those precalculus fundamentals are solid, though.

Comment: As much as I like Stewart for single variable calculus is as much as I dislike it for multivariable calculus. I did not find it to be a very good treatment overall. The quality is night and day between the two.

Comment: My college's typical multivariable class uses *Calculus, One and Several Variables* (Salas, Hille, Etgen), and from what I have seen of the text it seems servicable and many students learn multi for the first time through this text. If you are willing to take a leap into the deep end, you could jump right into Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* or Munkres' *Anaylsis on Manifolds*, the latter of which I used to learn multi for the first time, due to some peculiar curriculum choices from my college. (Would not reccomend in view of the "slightly less experienced" qualification).

Comment: Vol I & II of Apostol's Calculus could be at the right level for you. He teaches multivariable calculus (and linear algebra) in Vol II so you may want to skip ahead to that book, and just dip into Vol I on an as-needed basis.

Comment: At the bottom of [this page](https://cty.jhu.edu/programs/online/courses/multivariable-calculus-mvc) there is a "Learn More" section with contact information and the statement "Reach out to our team and ask any questions.". Perhaps they can help.